# Trying to add a detail product component. React-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-component

I have a component `products` which lists every product in the `/Products`url. I'm trying to make another component `Detail`  that displays specific `product` in the browser. This is the URL I've been trying to create `Detail/{some id goes here}`. The problem is how am i going to know which `product` clicked, so how am I supposed to show this specific `product` in the `Detail` component. I do have a `Detail` and `Products`component.

My router is below:

```
      <Router>
      <NavbarComponent></NavbarComponent>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/home">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/Products">
            <Products />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/Detail/:int">
            <Detail />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
```

I'm not going to share my `Products`component since It's composed 200 lines of code. I'm just gonna share the search `svg` in my `Products` that I want it to take me to the `Detail/{id}`page when I click.

```
        {filtered.map((product, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <div className="card shadow" style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
                <img
                  className="card-img-top"
                  src="https://dl.airtable.com/.attachmentThumbnails/65708b701baa3a84883ad48301624b44/2de058af"
                  alt="Card image cap"
                />
                <Link className="link" to={"Detail",index}>
                  <svg
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    fill="white"
                    stroke-width="0"
                    viewBox="0 0 512 512"
                    height="1em"
                    width="1em"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  >
                    <path d="M505 442.7L405.3 343c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H372c27.6-35.3 44-79.7 44-128C416 93.1 322.9 0 208 0S0 93.1 0 208s93.1 208 208 208c48.3 0 92.7-16.4 128-44v16.3c0 6.4 2.5 12.5 7 17l99.7 99.7c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0l28.3-28.3c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.6.1-34zM208 336c-70.7 0-128-57.2-128-128 0-70.7 57.2-128 128-128 70.7 0 128 57.2 128 128 0 70.7-57.2 128-128 128z"></path>
                  </svg>
                </Link>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you will need - https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params/

In summary, the `:int` can be availed in the `Detail` component as `const {int} = useParams();`. And while handling the click in the `Products` component, you will have to pass the product-id as `/Details/{productId}` using the `Link` component.

In this manner once the `Link` is clicked to bring the route to `Detail/xyz-product-id`, the `Detail` component will render having that `xyz-product-id` available as `int` in the code.

Comment: This worked a bit but not really. For example, when I'm at the url ```Detail/{some integer id}``` If I want to go my ```About``` page and click ```About``` link on my Navbar, It directs me to this url ```Detail/About``` even tho I just wanted to go ```About```url.

Comment: This is not a related issue btw. But that could be due to the value of `to` prop given to `Link` in the `navbar`. I think it would be resolved if you will provide `/About` to the `to` prop rather than just `About`.

Comment: It worked thanks. I got another question now lol. I actually don't want to get ```id``` from ```url``` I want to pass specific ```product```to my ```Detail``` component from my ```Products```component when I click the button. Is there a way to achieve this ? beacuse I don't want to make lots of requests to my database.

Comment: Hire me. lol. If that product's value is primitive. You can pass it as the `id` otherwise try passing the product object to `JSON.stringify` and pass the resultant string to the url - but will make the url really big and may also not record the whole string. So, if that is insufficient - look for some state-management solution such as redux, etc.